# Do Ideone and Codepad really not support C++03?

Tags: c++, value-initialization, codepad

My question is related to [Prasoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165520/prasoon-saurav)'s [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931312/value-initialization-and-non-pod-types) about non POD types and value initialization.

I tried the following code on online compilers like Ideone and Codepad but the executables gave runtime error on both the sites.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct Struct {
    std::string String;
    int Int;
    bool k;
};

struct InStruct:Struct
{
   InStruct():Struct(){}
};

int main()
{
   InStruct i;
   assert ( i.Int == 0);
   std::cout << "Hello";
}
```

Ideone Output [here](http://ideone.com/crcSI)
Codepad Output [here](http://codepad.org/B0YeAsm8)

Does that mean neither of them support C++03 value initialization feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does that mean neither of them support C++03 value initialization feature?

Yes.

Prior to version 4.4, GCC did not completely support value initialization ([the Boost GCC compatibility header](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/trunk/boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp) explains this and has links to the relevant GCC defect reports; see line 77).

If your code needs to be portable, you should be very careful relying on value initialization; GCC did not support it fully until recently and Visual C++ does not fully support it even in its latest version, Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration

```
InStruct i;
```

does not invoke value initialization

> $8.5.3/10 - "An object whose
>   initializer is an empty set of
>   parentheses, i.e., (), shall be
>   value-initialized."

If you want to value-initialize, you would require an expression something like

```
assert(InStruct().Int == 0);
```

Comment: `InStruct` has a default constructor.

Comment: @James McNellis: But the base class 'Struct' does not (which as 'Int')

Comment: @Chubsdad : The compiler synthesized default constructor of `Struct` performs `zero initialization` in this case.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: Is there some reference for this 'zero initialization' which is being done in the case?

Comment: @Chubsdad:  Yes, it's the list of initialization forms in 8.5.  `InStruct i` invokes the default constructor of `InStruct`, `Struct()` value initializes the base class, and value initialization for PODs is the same as zero initialization.

Comment: @James McNellis: So why do we say that value initialization is not supported? Also would like to know that since Struct has 'std::string' type, is Struct a POD?

Comment: @Chubsdad:  Sorry, I missed a step.  `Struct()` value initializes the `Struct` base class subobject.  Value initialization for a class type with only trivial constructors causes value initialization of each of the class type's member variables, so `String`, `Int`, and `k` are each value initialized (these are absolutely terrible variable names...).  `String` ends up getting its default constructor invoked and `Int` and `k` are each zero-initialized.

Comment: Value initialization is not fully supported because if it were, the member variables of the `Struct` base class subobject should be initialized but they are not.

Comment: @Chubsdad: `..is Struct a POD?` No it is not.

Comment: @Chubsdad:  No problem, but you can't thank me for the downvote; you'll have to thank whoever downvoted it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try [it](http://ideone.com/hKRvN) now! - Ideone supports GCC-4.5.1