# Clang 3.3 on Windows

Tags: c++, clang

I've downloaded http://www.ishani.org/clang/clang3.3_march2013.7z from http://www.ishani.org/web/articles/code/clang-win32/

now,

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cout << "Hallo";
}
```

produces

```
C:\clang>clang main.cpp
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include 
         ^
1 error generated.
```

How do I get the stdlib?

Comment: You need to get a standard library as well. See if [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) is available for Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It seems it does partially work on Windows: http://libcxx.llvm.org/results.Windows.html

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use `std::cout` as well?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, but this produces the same error.

Comment: @user5262: Sure, I was just stating the fact for completeness' sake.

Comment: libc++ does not work on windows (tried to compile it a few days ago on windows and it totally failed). Use libstc++ combined with mingw instead, works fine for me. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525245/getting-clang-to-work-on-windows carefully, especially this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6525707/1392778 .