# Why does zeroing out a structure cause lost of access to virtual base class members?

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2013

```
 struct base
 {
     int num;
     char ch;
     float fl;
 };

 struct ss : virtual base
 {
 };

 void main()
 {
     ss sa;

     sa.num = 100;

     cout << sa.num << endl;

     memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));        // set all members to zero

     cout <<  sa.num << endl;           // Access violation reading location 0x00000004.


 }
```

I can access members from a struct that is derived from a virtual base. When zeroing out the struct it also causes the lost of access to the members. Does this mean we would have to clear members individually instead of using memset or ZeroMemory?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour since `ss` is not a POD type. You're making zeroing it harder than it has to be: `ss sa{};`. And `void main` is bad; use `int main`.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast What if you want to clear a struct after using it?

Comment: `sa = ss{};` works safely and quickly

Comment: @user3613229, Alternatively, `sa = {};`.

Comment: @Mooing Duck Too much overhead. Why create a new object, initialize to zero and then copy it to the existing object?

Comment: @user3613229, I think the overhead is much smaller than you imagine. By the way, mine also creates a new object and assigns that to `sa`. I really can't see it differing much in overhead from `ZeroMemory` or something, though.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast So it's not possible to clear the object in the constructor? Why does this language have so much limitations.

Comment: @user3613229 What about to provide a method `ss::clear()`, if you're worried about the copy/move _'overhead'_??

Comment: If C++ has too many restrictions, you can try Java.

Comment: @Jefffrey That bad?? Be assured of my commiseration :P ...

Comment: @user3613229: I can't imagine why you think it's not possible to clear the object in the constructor, it's totally possible (and easy) to do that, but that's not what you asked us.

Comment: @Mysticial Someone should invent a new language simliar to C++ but without classess. If such a language does exist I would be so happy.

Comment: @user3613229 Um... that'd be C.

Comment: Or, you could just refrain from using classes. @Mysticial: There's a lot more than classes which C++ has that C doesn't.

Comment: I actually don't see why this question needs downvoting.

Comment: Just don't do `memset`. It's a sledgehammer. We do not do that any more. There are little implementation details here that you cannot see, and you're bulldozing right over them with no regard whatsoever.

Comment: We opt for the *overhead* now.

Comment: @DeadMG: No, neither do I. The _code_ needs downvoting (and so, possibly, does the author), but the question is fairly reasonable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley *shhhhh... I think your sarcasm detector is failing.* :)

Comment: @user3613229 Try template meta programming. Fun language I assure you.

Comment: @Jefffrey, The OP *didn't* want overhead.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast That's the point. With template meta programming you get almost `0` runtime overhead.

Comment: @Jefffrey, [Not you, too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249598/why-does-zeroing-out-a-structure-cause-lost-of-access-to-virtual-base-class-memb#comment37457666_24249598)

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast: Not you, too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I don't even know anymore. Mine blew up and now I'm just hopelessly bluffing.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast Dude, that's not how sarcasm works.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38103250/3223828 (particularly for non C++11 solutions).

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: 
Undefined behaviour. Full stop.

Long answer:
`base` is a virtual base of `ss`. Thus, it is unknown at compile time at which offset from the beginning of `ss` the parent `base` is located. This `offset` information must be retrieved at runtime. The information is stored in the `vtable` of the object.

So in order to know the offset of fields in `base`, the `vtable` pointer (which resides inside the object) has to be considered. You just nulled this `vtable`  pointer by nulling the whole struct. So when it is dereferenced to look up the offset, everything is about to blow up. The offset of `base` seems to be at offset `4` from the beginning of the `vtable`, this is why you get an access violation at address `4`.

Comment: So... `memset((char*)&sa + sizeof(void*), 0, sizeof(sa) - sizeof(void*))`? ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow  Why not simply `sa.num = 0; sa.ch = '\0'; sa.fl = 0.0; `?

Comment: @FredOverflow: That assumes that the vptr is based at 0.