# Complicated class member construction

Tags: c++, initialization

Since I know that it is generally much nicer to initialize all members in the initializer list of the constructor, I would like to know if it is also possible to do some more complicated construction in c++ inside the initializer list. In my program I would like to construct a class that initializes two of it's member vectors. Since I'm using them a Lot I would like to cache the contents, therefore I want to create the vectors at construction.

**edit** The main reason I want to cache these values that I can generate the the x and y coordinates from a circle with any radius without the need to recompute the sin and cosine values. So I'm using n (n_samples) for the granularity of sinx and cosy vector, which I use as lookup table internally.

So is it possible to do the initialization inside the initializer list, in such way that the constructor only needs to know how many samples it should create?

**Please note: While writing a short self contained question I wrote sinx and cosy for the vectors with respectively x and y coordinates of a circle. I could change this but then I would invalidate answers below. The sinus of angle gives a y-coordinate and the cosine will give a x value typically.**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class circular {

    public:

        circular( unsigned n = 20 );

        /* In my actual program I do much more 
         * complicated stuff. And I don't want
         * the user of this class to be bothered
         * with polar coordinates.
         */
        void print_coordinates( std::ostream& stream, double radius );

    private:

        unsigned            number_of_samples;

        std::vector<double> sinx;
        std::vector<double> cosy;
};

circular::circular( unsigned n )
    :
        number_of_samples(n) //I would like to initialize sinx cosy here.
{
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < number_of_samples; ++i ){
        sinx.push_back( std::sin( 2*M_PI / number_of_samples*i ) );
        cosy.push_back( std::cos( 2*M_PI / number_of_samples*i ) );
    }
}

void
circular::print_coordinates( std::ostream& stream, double r)
{
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < sinx.size(); ++i  ) {
        stream    << "{ "         << 
                     sinx[i] * r  << 
                     " , "        <<
                     cosy[i] * r  <<
                     " } "        <<
                     std::endl;
    }
}

int main () {
    circular c(20);
    c.print_coordinates(std::cout, 4);
    c.print_coordinates(std::cout, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

many thanks for your effort.

Heteperfan

Comment: Why bother? Just add `reserve()` calls before you fill the vectors.

Comment: I doubt very much it will be beneficial to use an initializer list to calculate a large number of cos/sin values. The cos/sin calculation will be far greater than the overhead of a for-loop.

Comment: This is why I want to cache them. I'm using the cos and sin values internally and I only want to construct compute them basically once. Is it possible at all to get this behavior?

Comment: This is perfectly fine. And probably the best solution, see my answer. You should drop the unnecessary number_of_samples member though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call a function to initialize member variables, so you can write a couple of helper functions:

```
static std::vector<double> get_sinx(unsigned n)
{
    std::vector<double> sinx;
    sinx.reserve(n);
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        sinx.push_back( std::sin( 2*M_PI / n*i ) );
    return sinx;
}

static std::vector<double> get_cosy(unsigned n)
{
    std::vector<double> cosy;
    cosy.reserve(n);
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        cosy.push_back( std::cos( 2*M_PI / n*i ) );
    return cosy;
}

circular::circular( unsigned n )
    : number_of_samples(n), sinx(get_sinx(n)), cosy(get_cosy(n))
{ }
```

With a decent compiler the [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) will mean there's no additional overhead (except for doing two `for` loops instead of one)

**Edit:** In C++11 you can use delegating constructors to create a temporary object that stores the result of some calculations, pass that to another constructor, and then initialize members using the result, see page 24 of [Overload 113](http://www.accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload113.pdf) for more details (the article it refers to was in [Overload 112](http://www.accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload112.pdf).)  This allows a single helper function to be used to provide the initialization for multiple members. Your example could become something like:

```
circular::circular( unsigned n )
    : circular(n, makeCoords(n))
{ }

private:

struct Coords {
    std::vector<double> x;
    std::vector<double> y;
};

Coords makeCoords(unsigned n);  // calculate values

circular::circular( unsigned n, Coords coords )
    : number_of_samples(n), sinx(coords.x), cosy(coords.y)
{ }
```

Comment: Note that this is not better than doing the same work in the constructor. The use of initialization lists is usually suggested as a way to reduce the cost of having to default construct before setting the values, but that does not apply here (the default construction is just moved to the function)...

Comment: And the default constructor for `std::vector` has very little cost anyway.  I'm not arguing in favour of using these helpers, just showing how, because that's what was asked.

Comment: As OP I'm actually going for Sebastians solution, however I selected this answer since I think this was the best answer to the question as I wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way to do it is to create iterators that lazily compute desired values, and use `std::vector(begin, end)`-style constructor.

Edit: added complete, self-contained example.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

// Parameterized with the transforming function, so that we don't need separate
// implementations for sine and cosine
template <double f(double)>
struct fun_iterator : std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, double>
{
    fun_iterator(int n, int i = 0)
    : i(i), n(n)
    { }

    double operator * () const
    {
        return f(i * M_PI / n);
    }

    fun_iterator operator ++ (int) 
    {
        fun_iterator copy(*this);
        ++ (*this);
        return copy;
    }

    fun_iterator& operator ++ ()
    {
        ++ i;
        return *this;
    }

    friend bool operator == (const fun_iterator& a, const fun_iterator& b)
    {
        return a.i == b.i && a.n == b.n;
    }

    friend bool operator != (const fun_iterator& a, const fun_iterator& b)
    {
        return ! (a == b);
    }

private:
    int i;
    int n;
};

struct with_values
{
    with_values(int n)
    : sine(fun_iterator<std::sin>(n), fun_iterator<std::sin>(n, n))
    , cosine(fun_iterator<std::cos>(n), fun_iterator<std::cos>(n, n))
    { }

    std::vector<double> sine;
    std::vector<double> cosine;
};
```

For the record: by no means is that more efficient than your original version. To this end, `reserve` mentioned by others I believe to be the only possible improvement. It's only an answer to your question, not a recommendation.

Edit 2: Actually, with a little bit of additional effort, this solution can be made as efficient as explicitly calling reserve. I've checked libstdc++ vector implementation, and given at least `forward_iterator`, the `(begin, end)` constructor determines the difference between begin and end iterators and allocates the memory before copying, just as if the `reserve` was called. For just `forward_iterator`it is still not optimal, as the difference is determined by successively incrementing the copy of the `begin` iterator. This is not, hovewer, the case for `random_access_iterator`. By making our iterator `random_access_iterator` we get one allocation and constant time.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize the vectors in the initializer list with Jonathan's solution. **But there is no reason to do so.**

When a variable is not initialized through the initializer list, it is first default initialized ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251707/default-initialization-in-c)) and this default (often uninitialized) value is then overwritten in the constructor body. This should be avoided by initializing a variable only once in the initializer-list.

Your example does not suffer from this problem. The vector's default constructor creates a perfectly valid empty vector both in your case and in Jonathan's solution. This vector is then filled with values, reallocating as it goes. If anything, Jonathan's solution is longer than yours and introduces unnecessary functions.

The only possible improvement is to preallocate the vectors and drop the unnecessary `number_of_samples` member:

```
circular::circular( unsigned n ) { 
   sinx.reserve(n);
   cosy.reserve(n);

   // fill both like you did
}
```

If n is small, this is probably premature optimization, too.

Comment: +1, however if the members are `const` then they must be initialized in the initializer list, so using a helper function is useful in that case.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That is true of course. Dito for members without useful default construction.

Comment: I would not call this *premature-optimization* even in the case of a small number of elements. If anything it can have a greater impact (percentage of time) for small sizes, since the 'constant' cost of memory allocation is spread over a smaller set of values. Some `std::vector` implementation I have seen will follow a 1.5 growth value starting with 1, yielding the following sequence of allocations: 1, 2, 3, 8, 12; others do 2x yielding 1, 2, 4, 8, 16. For a vector with 10 elements it means that both strategies generate 5 separate allocations.

Comment: Note, to me *premature* means that you are making the code less clear, or worse performing in an attempt to obtain some small performance advantage. But I don't think that to be the case here, if anything the code is clearer: `sinx.reserve(n)` tells the maintainer that you expect the vector to be of that size, and this really improves the performance.