# Calling a C++ constructor without parameter does not set values to 0

Tags: c++

Can someone explain why my constructor is not setting Fraction c,d,e values to 0 when no parameter is provided? Results are: Fraction c=0,0 d=0,6e23 e=6e23,0.

I have found the workaround of setting `Fraction::Fraction() {}` to `Fraction::Fraction() : m_num(0), m_deno(0) {}` but I thought using `Fraction::Fraction() {}` would mean filling the values with 0s...

```
class Fraction {
public:
Fraction(double num, double deno);
Fraction(double num);
Fraction();

private:
double m_num;
double m_deno;
};

int main() {

Fraction a(4,5);      // a=4/5
Fraction b(2);        // b=2/1 
Fraction c, // c=0/0
         d, // d=0/6e23
         e; // e=6e23/0
return 0;
}

Fraction::Fraction() {}
Fraction::Fraction(double num) : m_num(num), m_deno(1) {}
Fraction::Fraction(double num, double deno) : m_num(num), m_deno(deno) {}
```

Comment: Because there is no code that would do so? I don't see a single line here that would attempt to set anything to 0. *"I thought using Fraction::Fraction() {} would mean filling the values with 0s..."* - you thought wrong. Unless you explicitly specify how a member should be constructed it will be *default constructed* (which means that nothing is initialized in the case of `double`)

Comment: `m_num` and `m_deno` don't start as `0` any more than they would if they were just function local variables. Another way of specifying starting values would be to use [default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

Comment: You need to set those values to zero yourself. Otherwise it is just displaying the location of memory of c, d ,e

Comment: it is always good to set member variables to the values that you expect in the constructor, never take anything for granted. alt. assign in the declaration C++17

Comment: Also, tangential, are you sure you _want_ `m_deno` to be `0` in a default-constructed `Fraction`? Perhaps `0/1` for a default value would make more sense than `0/0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not assign default values to C++ default types (for example: int, float, char) class variables inside the constructor, they are not going to be defaulted to zero. That will lead you to undefined behaviour.
Check here to see in which cases the variables will be zero: [Default initialization in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251707/default-initialization-in-c)

If you want them to be zero:

```
    private:
    double m_num = 0;
    double m_deno = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you set those c, d, and e to be 0, if that is what you want it to be. Otherwise it is just going to be the value of a memory location of c, d, and e. I suggest you initialize them to 0, if that is what you want from them.

```
int main() {

Fraction a(4,5);      // a=4/5
Fraction b(2);        // b=2/1 
Fraction c(0);
Fraction d(0);
Fraction e(0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if only one parameter is provided my constructor will set the second to be 1 so it would not work to set both values to 0.

Comment: @ValentinJub You can try using a delegating constructor `Fraction(double num) : Fraction(num, 1) {}`

Comment: @ValentinJub oh, I wasn't sure which constructor you were using to call c, d, and e. I just did the one with one parameter. Feel free to edit it on how it should be.